# Hibernate JPA Cascade Delete on ManyToMany unidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the following classes:

```
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT(11) UNSIGNED")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

```
public class Playlist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT(11) UNSIGNED")
    private Long id;


    @ManyToMany
    @CollectionTable(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"maps_id", "playlist_id"}))
    private List<Map> songs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The idea is to be able to create multiple "playlists" and in each one to be able to add multiple "songs". The same "song" can be in several "playlists".

My question is: How can I delete a "song" and have it automatically removed from all playlists that contain it?

The idea is to make the relationship look like this:

[image: PhpMyAdmin relationship]

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you are asking for - seems you just want/need the ON DELETE Cascade set on the FK in the relational table. You will have to modify the DDL scripts yourself to add it. JPA DDL generation is a developer tool, so doesn't have all the bells and whistles your DB offers; JPA is aimed at java persistence, not database access. Also note that DB direct changes like this are efficient, but outside of the JPA model. This means that any cached playlists will still reference the now deleted song until they too are refreshed.

Comment: I'm trying not to put the relation in my "song" table and make it bidirectional. So I would like to know if there is any argument or annotation, for example \@ManyToMany, \@OnDelete, \@JoinTable, \@JoinColumn or any other, that helps me so that when I delete a song, they are also deleted in the automatically created table called "playlists_songs ". Is this possible without manually modifying the database structure?

Comment: there isn't. Playlist references Song and owns the relationship, so there is no way for it to know from Song that playlists reference it. JPA expects you do do the cleanup, or you will get FK constraint errors. The only way to get around that in JPA is to manually clear out these relationships yourself. either with JPQL/native SQL to remove references, or by reading in all Playlists referencing the song and removing it from their lists.

Comment: databases though have ON DELETE cascade options you can set on FKs, which is what you seem to be showing in your image. Setting that on your relation table/CollectionTable in the database will cause the database to automatically clear out those ManyToMany rows when you delete a referenced song. You just then need to deal with stale Playlist data in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete a song using its id the song will be deleted from all playlists.
For that, you have to use:

```
songRepository.deleteById(songId);
```

Comment: That's the way I usually delete. But this doesn't delete the records in the other tables because in the Song class there is no relationship to the Playlists.